# Reduce list with values from other list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

is it possible to reduce a list based on entries from another list?

Here is something similar:

```
list1.forEach(l1 -> {
    list2.forEach(l2 -> {
        if (l1.getId() == l2.getId())
            reducedActions.add(l2); // that's the new list where the filtered entries should be add
    });
});
```

Edit: What i excpect:

```
l1: 10, 15, ,16
l2: 1, 2, 12, 10, 11, 14, 16
reducedActions: 10, 16
```

Comment: What do you mean by reduce? Reduce (aggregation) and filter (selection) are two different things.

Comment: Can you just explain what result you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this?

```
Set<Integer> ids = list2.stream().map(e -> e.getId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<ElementType> reducedActions = list1.stream().filter(e -> ids.contains(e.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Don’t forget to assign the result of the second operation to a variable…

Comment: @Holger yes :) I just don't know what type of objects contains list1 and list2, and don't want to use List<Object> as a result.

Comment: Say `List<ElementType>` or similar. The reader should be able to adapt…

Comment: Note that original question rely on identity, whereas `HashSet` rely on equality ! You may use `keySet()` from an `IdentityHashMap` if identity matters.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! One thing, can you please edit you're post, you miss a bracket in the last line of code (at the end) and can you add `Collectors` to `toSet()` and `toList()`.

Comment: Add missed bracket and Collectors. But I'm prefer to use static import for toList() and toSet() methods.

Comment: Ok , I thought so but i might be confused other user there are not so familiar with this

Answer (score 0):

With [List.retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) it is as simple as:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(list2);
list.retainAll(list1);
```

Usage:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ReduceList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(10, 15, 16);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 12, 10, 11, 14, 16);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(list2);

        list.retainAll(list1);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```